Issue with openpyxl version 3.1.4: X and Y axis labels not displaying in Excel chart (It works with the version 3.1.2)
Title: Issue with openpyxl version 3.1.4: X and Y axis labels not displaying in Excel chart
Description
I encountered an issue with the openpyxl library where values on the X and Y axes are not displayed correctly in an Excel chart. This issue occurs with openpyxl version 3.1.4 but works correctly with version 3.1.2.
Environment

openpyxl version: 3.1.4 (problematic), 3.1.2 (working)
Python version: 3.11.9
Operating System: [Windows 10 and 11]

Steps to reproduce

Create a DataFrame with the following data:

import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference, Series
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.chart.axis import ChartLines

data = {
    'Year': ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023'],
    'serie_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'serie_2': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'serie_3': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a workbook and select the active worksheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Write the DataFrame to the worksheet
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

# Create a LineChart
chart = LineChart()
chart.title = "Revenue Over Years"
chart.style = 10
chart.x_axis.title = "Year"
chart.y_axis.title = "Revenue"

# Define categories (X axis values) using the first column (Year)
categories = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row)

# Add the series to the chart
for i in range(2, ws.max_column + 1):
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row)
    series = Series(values, title=ws.cell(row=1, column=i).value)
    chart.series.append(series)

chart.set_categories(categories)

# Set the size of the chart in centimeters
chart.width = 15  # Width in cm
chart.height = 10  # Height in cm

# Ensure axis labels and gridlines are displayed
chart.x_axis.majorGridlines = ChartLines()
chart.y_axis.majorGridlines = ChartLines()
chart.x_axis.tickLblPos = 'nextTo'
chart.y_axis.tickLblPos = 'nextTo'

# Position the chart on the sheet
ws.add_chart(chart, "E5")  # Position the chart starting from cell E5

# Save the Excel file
wb.save("test_graph.xlsx")

I would expect that the problem will be solved in a future version. I use the older one for the time being.
with version 3.1.4 of openpyxl only the label are displayed but not values (2015,2016,... on x and 1..11 on y)
I would help the other onfronted to it to save some time. Just try the version 3.1.2 to see if it solve your problem.

I would like to do so but I don’t know how as the official GitHub doesn’t show me the issues tab. I am open to any suggestions
